# Project PLINK eigenvector from one group on top of another group

Tags: snp, plink, pca

I have 1 `.bcf` file called with individuals from two groups, one which is my samples, another which is a reference panel. Due to my samples having a limited amount data, when I run PLINK to generate `.eigenvec`, none of the samples have any overlap. I believe this is due to the data being skewed. Therefore, I wish to generate a PCA from my reference panel and my samples separately, and then project my samples on top of the reference panel.

I tried from the PLINK file from the original `.bcf` file to extract the two groups, then identify which genotypes are equally well represented using parameters such as `--geno 0.1` to generate SNP's overlapping between the groups. Then I tried the following after reading a lot of different suggestions online, which generates a nice plot with the points projected on top of each other.

```
group1_eig <- fread("Samples.eigenvec")
group1_eig <- group1_eig[,3:ncol(group1_eig)]

group1_freq <- fread("Samples.frq")
group1_eval <- fread("Samples.eigenval")

# read in the files
group2_eig <- fread("RefPanel.eigenvec")
group2_eig <- group2_eig[,3:ncol(group2_eig)]

group2_freq <- fread("RefPanel.frq")
group2_eval <- fread("RefPanel.eigenval")

freq <- rbind(group1_freq, group2_freq)
eval <- rbind(group1_eval, group2_eval)
eig <- rbind(group1_eig, group2_eig)
pca <- prcomp(eig[,3:ncol(eig)], scale = TRUE)
group1_pca <- predict(pca, newdata = group1_eig[,3:ncol(group1_eig)], 
                      type = "scores")
```

Is this approach acceptable? What other approaches work? I have read you can also normalise one group using the square root of the eigenvalues for the other group. Or potentially use the MAF (`.frq`).